# C++ - When is the destructor called for an object that is used but not assigned?

Tags: c++, return-value, destructor

Example:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> GetPtr() { return std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(5)); }
...
void DoSomething() {
  int x = 2 + *GetPtr();
}
```

When is the destructor of the unique_ptr returned by GetPtr() called within DoSomething? Is it called after the call to 'operator+' or is it called once we leave the scope of 'DoSomething'?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try it and report back to us?

Comment: The destructor is called when the lifetime of the object ends. This depends on how it's used but this is detailed in the standard and has been covered in existing questions and answers here on SO. Hard to search from my phone so you'll have to put in the effort on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The draft standard N3936 S12.2/3 says:

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step
>   in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

S1.9/10:

> A full-expression is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression.

S1.9/14:

> Every value computation and side eﬀect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side eﬀect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

Note 8:

> 8) As speciﬁed in 12.2, after a full-expression is evaluated, a sequence of zero or more invocations of destructor functions for temporary objects takes place, usually in reverse order of the construction of each temporary object.

The full expression is the RHS of the assignment, and the sequence point occurs once that computation is complete. The temporary is destroyed after the '+' computation and before the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is called before operator+ is called, because `GetPtr()` is called, then the result of it is dereference, and copied.  the reference to the unique pointer belongs to the scope of the parameters of the + operator.  The last reference to the value is lost when the `operator*` is done, which is before the `operator+` is even called.

Comment: Technically, it's called "within the scope of" `operator*`.

Comment: thanks, I forgot about that, either way, it is destroyed before the operator+ is called.